# Finding the order of $G/G'$

Tags: group-theory

Please help me to find the order of the quotient group $G/G'$ such that

$$G= \langle a,b \mid a^{2^{n-1}}=1,b^2=a^{2^{n-2}},b^{-1}ab=a^{-1} \rangle$$ I don't know where to start and how to treat this group.  :-(

Comment: Note: when $n=3$, this group is not finite.

Comment: In the second relation, perhaps you mean $b^2=a^{2^{n-2}}$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Yes Andrea

Comment: Ok, thanks, please fix then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** In $G/G'$, $b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$ becomes $a^2=1$. Deduce that $G/G'$ is the direct product of two cyclic groups.

Answer (score 2):

Anothe hint may be to do some handy calculation by adding two new relations to $G$'s relations. I mean if you know the relations, add $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$ to $G's$ relation and work on them. I think you will get the answer. This is what @Seirios did in a small leading hint.

Comment: Hope you awaken to a wonderful day! + :-)